# How to find the maximum height of a binary search tree?

Tags: scheme, binary-search-tree

The height of a binary search is:

-0, if the tree is empty

-1 + (maximum of the height of the left subtree and the height of the right subtree).

For example:
(height empty) => 0

(height (make-node 2 "two" (make-node 1 "one" empty empty) empty))
=> 2

I wonder how to find the height of each subtree and how the recursion works. Thanks!

Comment: Uh, what?! The question gives you all the information you need. Your code simply needs to check whether the tree is empty, in which case return 0. (That's the base case.) Otherwise, get the height of the left subtree and right subtree, see which one is greater, and add 1 to that, and return that. (That's the recursive case.)

Comment: I don't understand why people can't do their homework by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation is very simple, you just have to translate in code what you already wrote in words. I won't spoil the fun for you, but I'll give you the general idea of the procedure, so you can reach the answer by your own means:

```
(define (height tree)
  (if <???>  ; if the tree is empty
      <???>  ; then return the height of the empty tree
      (<???> ; otherwise return 1 plus the maximum between
         (max (height <???>)     ; the height of the left subtree
              (height <???>))))) ; and the height of the right subtree
```

Comment: +1 Nice, a skeletal code form of what I said in words in the comment. ;-)